# ui-router prefixes nested view templates with the parent's url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent state (`parent`), and a child state (`parent.child`)

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('parent', {
            url: '/parent',
            templateUrl: 'views/parent.html',
            controller: 'parentController',
        })
        .state('parent.child', {
            url: '/:id',
            templateUrl: 'views/child.html',
            controller: 'childController',
        });
```

The parent view contains the nested `ui-view`

ie: In `views/parent.html`:

```
    <h1>Child:</h1>
    <div ui-view></div>
```

When I change to the child state, the parent state's url is being **prefixed** to the `templateUrl`.

ie: the `templateUrl` is being resolved as `/parent/views/child.html`

This fails because `/parent/views/child.html` doesn't exist. (The file is stored under `/views/child.html`)

How can I configure `ui-router` not to prefix the parent state's url onto the `templateUrl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a ui-router problem. You should prepend your template url with a slash, so that it's relative to the base-url instead of the current url.

So:

```
templateUrl : '/views/child.html'
```